# After Activity.onDestroy() method, why I can still get this activity's instance?

Tags: android

I have created a class to cache Activities, like:

```
public class ActivityList {

    public static List<WeakReference<Activity>> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void put(Activity activity) {
        list.add(new WeakReference<>(activity));
    }

}
```

and, the onDestroy method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log..e("test", "call onDestroy");
}
```

Secondly, I enable the "Don't keep activities" in System's developer options, to make sure an activity will be killed after I left

Then, I start an Activity and put an instance into then ActivityList class

```
ActivityList.put(this);
```

When I left this activity to another activity, the LogCat shows the first activity called onDestroy(). Then in then second activity, I get the first activity's instance like:

```
WeakReference<Activity> weakReference = ActivityList.list.get(0);
Activity activity = weakReference.get();
activity.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(this, "HHHH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Then code works well ?!
In my view, the first activity called onDestroy() then I cannot use it anymore, so the Toast should NOT show. AND after onDestroy(), there are no any strong references refer to the activity, it should be GC by system.

So, Why does it work?

Comment: please share your onDestroy() code of first activity

Comment: I had edit it. The code in onDestroy() just print a log

Answer (score 1):

Weak references should be cleared at Garbage Collection,but finish an activity may not trigger GC.

Comment: Any DOCs improved that "finish an activity may not trigger GC" ? I mean after onDestroy, the activity and it's instance should not be used any more

Comment: GC may happen at low memory time,but not related to any "finish" or "destory" call.

Comment: If the DOCs did not specifically say like "this method callback will trigger the gc",I think it should run according to default GC rules.